# Error running app: Default Activity not found (Android)

Tags: android, manifest

I found the same question in this place but the all answers didn't work for me (It works if I do: Select menu `Run -> Edit Configurations`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="es.package.launcher">
<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AppsListActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
</application>
```

Am I writing something wrong? Please point me out.

Comment: you forgot to add the Launcher filter to Intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not adding in your intent-filter

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

you missing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Comment: Please accept this answer so it is helpful fro others @ChenYo

Answer (score 2):

Add below line in your Intent-filter

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        **<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />**
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with below code. You need to add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in the `activity` tag in your Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="es.package.launcher">
<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            //Add this line
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AppsListActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
</application>
```